# AngularJS directive: Expression 'undefined' used with directive ... is non-assignable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a 2 week old Angular noob, and I've been attempting my first ever directive for over a day now. :P  I've read [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and [this](http://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/), which seem good directives introductions and a bunch of Stackoverflow answers, but I can't get this working.

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Main">
  <textarea caret caret-position="uiState.caretPosition"></textarea>
  {{uiState.caretPosition}}
</div>
```

and

```
angular.module('App', [])
  .controller('Main', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.uiState = {};
    $scope.uiState.caretPosition = 0;
  }])


  .directive('caret', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {caretPosition: '='},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var $el = angular.element(element);
        $el.on('keyup', function() {
          scope.caretPosition = $el.caret();
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dJty6/5/).  I'm basically trying to get the caret position within a textbox.  I'm using this [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/acdvorak/jquery.caret) in the fiddle (source of the .caret() method, which should just return a number).

My questions are

1. Do I even need a directive here?  [Ben Nadel says](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2476-My-Approach-To-Building-AngularJS-Directives-That-Bind-To-JavaScript-Events.htm) the best directives are the ones you don't have to write (amen to that!)
2. If yes, is this the right way to go about the directive?  Ie isolated scope with two-way bound variable?
3. If yes, when I run this code locally, I keep getting the error `Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'caret' is non-assignable!`.  I've read [the doc](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/error/%24compile/nonassign) and as far as I can tell I've followed instructions for how to fix to no avail.
4. BONUS: Why in jsfiddle do I get no such error. The fiddle just fails silently. What's with that?

Thanks!

Comment: I think @Lois's answer is more common for the angular problem in the title.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You were close.. The main problem is changing a scope variable inside an event that angular doesn't know about. When that event occurs, you have to tell angular that something changed by using `scope.$apply`.

```
  $el.on('keyup', function() {
      scope.$apply( function() {
        scope.caretPosition = $el.caret();
      });
  });
```

[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dJty6/6/)

For the questions:

1. yes, I don't think there's a way around having to write a directive for this.
2. in this case, it seems fine.
3. not sure, there are no problems in the jsfiddle. It sounds like you're setting `carat="something"` somewhere? check to make sure the html is the same as what's in the fiddle.
4. same as 3

Also note that if you click and move the caret, it won't update because it's only listening for keyup.

Comment: Damn, and I had already tried the scope.$apply based on this excellent article too! [link](http://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/the-8020-guide-to-writing-angularjs-directives/comment-page-1/) (slider example).  Must have had something else wrong at the time. Your answer fixes the fiddle, so accepted!  I was still getting the error in my app. It was indeed because the fiddle didn't match my code! :P There were a two textareas defined in my code and one was missing the caret-position attribute. A case of many concurrent errors, and not knowing which one the error msg is describing!

Comment: Submitted [request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/6725) to update the Angular docs

Answer (score 23):

My solution was harder to find out here, but easier to implement. I had to change it to the equivalent of;

```
  scope: {caretPosition: '=?'},
```

(Note that the question mark makes the attribute optional. Prior to 1.5 this apparently wasn't required.)